# RestKit JSON null value crash

Tags: ios, json, swift, restkit

I have this problem. I am developing app in Swift and using RestKit to retrieve and post data back to API. However I have hit road block. If retrieved JSON payload contains some null value, the app wil crash with message:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1994faba0'

What do I do?
The mapped properties are Strings.

Mapped object:

```
public class User: NSObject {

    public var id: Int? = 0
    public var email: String?
    public var firstName: String?
    public var lastName: String?
    public var name: String?
    public var office: String?
    public var phone: String?
    public var company: String?

}
```

Mapping:

```
let userMapping = RKObjectMapping(forClass: User.self)
userMapping.addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary([
    "id": "id",
    "email": "email",
    "first_name": "firstName",
    "last_name": "lastName",
    "name": "name",
    "company": "company",
    "phone": "phone",
    "office": "office",
])
let responseDescriptor = RKResponseDescriptor(mapping: userMapping, pathPattern: currentUserPath, keyPath: "data", statusCodes: NSIndexSet(index: 200))
objectManager.addResponseDescriptor(responseDescriptor)
```

JSON response:

```
{
  "status": "ok",
  "data": {
    "id": 1,
    "email": "some@email.com",
    "created_at": 1418832714451,
    "updated_at": 1421077902126,
    "admin": true,
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Doe",
    "company": null,
    "office": null,
    "phone": null,
    "name": "John Doe"
  }
}
```

It crashes on each of these: office, phone and name.

Comment: Show the JSON and your mapping. Improve the JSON. Add handling for NSNull to your code.

Comment: I have edited my question to satisfy your request :) How do I handle NSNull myself with RestKit?

Comment: What version are you using (it should convert to nil really)

Comment: RestKit 0.24.0, Xcode 6.1.1, iOS 8.1

Comment: If i remove company, office and phone from mapping, it works just fine.

Comment: Really you don't want the JSON to include `null`, just to omit the key/value pair if there is no content. But RestKit should nil the item in the mapped object (functionally that is a route to delete existing data when updating)

Comment: Well, it doesnt, What should I do now?

Comment: it works with RestKit version 0.20.3

Comment: You mean you get no crash and nil in the mapped object in v0.20.3 but not in v0.24.0 ?

Comment: Yes, thats right. RestKit still screams "Coercing NSNull value to nil in shouldSetValue:atKeyPath: -- should be fixed.", but doesn't crash.

Comment: The `null` values in the JSON are perfectly valid.  If your code isn't handling them it's not due to a fault of the JSON.  Note that the `null` value could be mapped as either a `nil` pointer or as an `NSNull` object, and apparently RestKit is doing the latter.  I suggest you examine the documentation for RestKit and see how it claims to handle `null` and adjust your code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use another version of RestKit. There were changes in RestKit codebase regarding the null value bindings.

Comment: i did try older version where it maps null in JSON as nil in Swift/Obj-C

Comment: @ZdeněkTopič can u tell which version?

Answer (score 0):

@Hotlicks is right, nulls should be handled by the client. I believe the reason for this crash is that Restkit cannot properly introspect class property types in Swift. We solved this in our project by adding explicit targetClass to our RKObjectMapping. So, instead of using the addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary method, try:

```
let userMapping = RKObjectMapping(forClass: User.self)
let simpleMapping = RKAttributeMapping(fromKeyPath: "first_name", toKeyPath: "firstName")
simpleMapping.propertyValueClass = NSString.classForCoder() // we used class for coder when we did our project, but you might have success with something else.
userMapping.addPropertyMapping(simpleMapping)
```

You have to do the same for relationships as well, like so:

```
let relationshipMapping = RKRelationshipMapping(fromKeyPath: "person", toKeyPath: "person", withMapping: Person.self)
relationshipMapping.propertyValueClass = Person.classForCoder()
userMapping.addPropertyMapping(relationshipMapping)
```

This allows an automatic conversion from NSNull to an Swift optional.